# Direct3D apps crash on other computers

Tags: c#, .net, crash, mdx, direct3d

I've developed several Direct3D applications using Visual C# Express 2008 (MDX).  They all run without a problem on my computer but when I try to run them on other people's computers, they crash.  I tried using Clickonce to install them but they still crash.  I'm developing them on Windows 7, and they crash on most Win Vista, 7, and 8 PC's, but never on XP which is weird.

Most of my apps keep a log file for diagnostics and the first thing they are programmed to do is write a "Startup" line to the log file, but they never even get that far.  I don't get the normal .NET "unhandled exception" error; it crashes before the runtime even starts.

It has to have something to do with the DirectX libraries (none of my other apps ever crash), but I know all the computers have DirectX and .NET installed, so I'm quite baffled by this.  If I'm linking to nonstandard libraries then I would assume ClickOnce would package them with my app when I publish it.

I know most of you would say to use SlimDx, and I do want to do that but before I port all my apps over I would like to be able to distribute them as they are.

Since my app can't even start up, I'm unable to track down the cause.  Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: It's a long-shot, but perhaps you're missing D3DCompiler_43.dll? It doesn't seem to be bundled by default with a Windows install; we had to include it in an installer. Also, can you use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645) to monitor your application on start up and see which DLLs it's attempting to load?

Comment: Interesting, I'm not sure what that DLL does but I think I do use custom shaders in all of the apps that are crashing.  There is not a reference to that DLL in my project but I will look into that. (However I thought that due to lazy loading it wouldn't crash until I tried to compile HLSL).  I'll also check out Process Monitor.  Surprised I never heard of that before.